# ESP8266 WIFI_AP_STA issue

Tags: c, esp8266

Im using ESP8266 in mode WIFI_AP_STA...I ave issue for soft AP. Some time , i don't understand why, client (PC o mobile) joint to AP, ping but don't receive data (webpage). I know issue related to single channel ad start AP after ESP8226 station is connected at same channel.

```
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.softAPdisconnect();
  WiFi.disconnect();
  WiFi.setAutoConnect(false);
  delay(1000);
  
  ip.fromString(HostIp.c_str());
  mask.fromString(HostSubnetMask.c_str());

  WiFi.begin(ClientSSID, ClientPassword);
  WiFi.hostname("CV19Archimede");

  delay(500);

  WiFi.softAPConfig(ip, ip, mask); 

  WifiRetry = 0;
  while((WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) && ( WifiRetry < WIFIRETRY)) 
  {
    delay(500);
    WifiRetry ++;
    if (WifiRetry > WIFIRETRY) 
    {
      WiFi.disconnect();
    }
  }

  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Wifichannel = WiFi.channel();
  }
  else
  {
    Wifichannel = 1;
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  }

  //Serial.println(Wifichannel);
  
//  WiFi.softAPConfig(ip, ip, mask); 
  WiFi.softAP(HostSSID, HostPassword,Wifichannel);

  delay(500);
```